# loading gem runt-0.9.0 - upgrading old rails destop application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I was trying to move an older Rails-App from an outdated Debian PC (Ruby 2.1., Rails 4.1.6) to a PC running a current Ubuntu 18LTS (Ruby 2.6.3, Rails 4.2.10). Being a Windows .Net programmer, I am rather inexperienced with Rails apps on Linux. Since this is for a non-Profit, I'm stuck with that.

At least I made it that far, that it is starting the initialization of the actual "vtrack" app. But there it is aborting with this error message.

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- date/format
/home/guest/dev/vtrack/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/runt-0.9.0/lib/runt.rb:37:in `require'
/home/guest/dev/vtrack/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/runt-0.9.0/lib/runt.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
/home/guest/dev/vtrack/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

The code block in questioin inside the runt.rb file is

```
...
require 'yaml'
require 'time'
require 'date'
require 'date/format'
require "runt/version"
require "runt/dprecision"
...
```

I'm not sure where the 'date/format' library is located - and whether e.G. a downgrade to Rails 4.1.6 would solve the problem - or whether I rather just messed up the whole system.

Thanks for any advice.

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in runt, which was fixed in https://github.com/mlipper/runt/commit/7fcf4af73753adcf28b8cd0a0ac4eb92a0a190a7 in 2016, but never released. Taking into account that the last runt release was in 2013 and that only works for Ruby < 2.3, I would stop using this gem. But you can try one of this options to fix it:

- The easiest: Remove `require 'date/format'` from your local `runt.rb` (and hope that this is the only fix needed)
- Point to the current version of runt in Github in your Gemfile (as it included the fix): https://github.com/mlipper/runt (again, hope that no more fixes are needed)

In case it is not clear, a downgrade to Rails 4.1.6 won't fix the issue. A downgrade to Ruby 2.2 may fix it, but it is a good idea to move to a newer Ruby version (2.2 is unsupported and it no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates).
Also, an update from Ruby 2.1 to Ruby 2.6 may be difficult. You may want to do a more gradual update (From Ruby 2.1 to Ruby 2.2, From 2.2 to 2.3 and so on) and the same for Rails.